# Spring Retry not retrying in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch, spring-retry

I have a config file that has:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx" })
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import(DataSourceConfig.class)
@EnableRetry
public class BatchConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {
```

and another method in a separate class that has:

```
    @Override
    @Retryable(ValidationException.class)
    public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExec, StepExecution stepExec) {
        boolean passed = validationStatus.getValidationStatus();
        if(!passed) {
            LOG.info("******Batch job validation FAILED******");
            throw new ValidationException("Batch job validation FAILED");
        }
        else return FlowExecutionStatus.COMPLETED;
    }
```

At the very least it should retry and print this 3 times instead of once, since it does not pass. All the annotations are imported successfully. Its just not doing what I would expect.:

```
******Batch job validation FAILED******
```

All I get is the stacktrace for the one ValidationException

```
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.item.validator.ValidationException: Batch job validation FAILED
    at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.decision.ValidationFlowDecider.decide(ValidationFlowDecider.java:31)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `decide` method is part of the `JobExecutionDecider` contract and will be driven by the flow you defined for your job. So if you want to "retry" some logic in your job flow, you should define it in the flow definition itself, not using an annotated method (with Spring Retry or any other library).

A typical usage of a decider is shown with a code example in the reference documentation here: [Programmatic Flow Decisions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#programmaticFlowDecisions).

Comment: In that case, I'd like to remove it from the decider and put it directly on a Step, but that doesnt seem to work either.